# Swift Error: Variable used within its own initial value

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

When I'm initializing an instance of an entity I'm getting the error `Variable used within its own initial value`.

Here is the code throwing the error:

```
class func buildWordDefinition (word:String, language:Language, root:TBXMLElement) -> WordDefinition
    {
        let word = WordDefinition(word: word, language: language)
```

The error points at the `word` variable.

Here is the WordDefinition class:

```
class WordDefinition {
    let word: String
    let language: Language

    init(word: String, language:Language)
    {
        self.word = word
        self.language = language
    }
}
```

What does this error mean ?

Comment: Maybe you shouldnt call the object `word`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are declaring a constant named `word`, and trying to use the argument with the same name to initialize it. The compiler tries to use the just declared constant to assign its own initial value, instead of using the argument.

Answer (score 22):

> I have faced same error when missing out **if** while unwrapping the
>   text .

[image]

**By adding if resolved above issue.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, had the same stupid mistake and couldn't see it :P

Answer (score 11):

You are redefining a constant `word` which has the same name as a parameter within your function

```
class func buildWordDefinition (word:String, language:Language, root:TBXMLElement) -> WordDefinition
{
    // same name as the parameter here
    let word = WordDefinition(word: word, language: language)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a function parameter called `word` in scope and you're trying to create a constant with the same name. Name your constant something other than `word`.